# Is there a better way of doing this? ASP.NET/C#/Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I created this method so it would update a LABEL on the page. What we have here is a bunch of checkboxes indicating if the person has any limitations. When the user logs on and sees the checkboxes, I want the label to display the ones that are checked making it easier for the user to see what limitations the person has.

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET and what I want to know, is there a better/easier/more efficient way of going about this? The first thing I found was String.Concat which is why I used it in the code below. Also, I can't seem to get a line return (a (br /)) to work in the code behind (I do understand that (br /) won't work in the code behind). I've tried many different methods and none seem to work which is why I threw a COMMA in the string. Any suggestions?

```
protected void LblLimitsLabel()
{
    String strBend = "", strDryDust = "", strStanding = "", strHearing = "", strHeights = "", strHepatitis = "", strLifting = "", strMachines = "", strPulling = "", strPushing = "", strReaching = "", strSeizures = "", strSuddenTemp = "", strVisual = "", strWalking = "", strWheelchair = "", strHelmet = "", strOther = "";

   if (chkBend.Checked)
       strBend = "Bend/Stoop, ";

   if (chkDryDusty.Checked)
       strDryDust = "Dry/Dusty, ";

   if (chkHearing.Checked)
       strHearing = "Hearing, ";

   if (chkHeights.Checked)
       strHeights = "Heights, ";

   if (chkHepatitis.Checked)
       strHepatitis = "Hepatitis, ";

   if (chkLifting.Checked)
       strLifting = "Lifting, ";

   if (chkMachines.Checked)
       strMachines = "Machines, ";

   if (chkPulling.Checked)
       strPulling = "Pulling, ";

   if (chkPushing.Checked)
       strPushing = "Pushing, ";

   if (chkReaching.Checked)
       strReaching = "Reaching, ";

   if (chkSeizures.Checked)
       strSeizures = "Seizures, ";

   if (chkStanding.Checked)
       strStanding = "Standing, ";

   if (chkSuddenTemp.Checked)
       strSuddenTemp = "Sudden Temp. Changes, ";

   if (chkVisual.Checked)
       strVisual = "Visual, ";

   if (chkWalking.Checked)
       strWalking = "Walking, ";

   if (chkWheelchair.Checked)
       strWheelchair = "Wheelchair, ";

   if (chkHelmet.Checked)
       strHelmet = "Helmet, ";

   strOther = TextBox1.Text;

   LblLimits.Text = String.Concat(strBend, strDryDust, strStanding, strHearing, strHeights, strHepatitis, strLifting, strMachines, strPulling, strPushing, strReaching, strSeizures, strSuddenTemp, strVisual, strWalking, strWheelchair, strHelmet, strOther);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this. What's the best way for a programmer to go about this.. Looks like I got a few answers below.. I was also wondering how to get a line break in between words..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to build a string. Use AppendLine to create a new line.
2. Put your if statements on single lines. It will be easier to read for short if statements like this.
3. If you need new lines to appear in in an ASP.NET Label, you will need to embed `<br/>` tags.

   ```
   StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

   if (chkBend.Checked) SB.AppendLine("Bend/Stoop, ");
   if (chkDryDusty.Checked) SB.AppendLine("Dry/Dusty, ");
   // and so on

   SB.Append(TextBox1.Text);
   LblLimits.Text = SB.ToString();
   ```

When you get more comfortable with C# and ASP.NET, I suggest moving on to a databound control like [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)

**References**

- [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)
- [StringBuilder.AppendLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebk18257.aspx)
- [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)

Comment: that also makes his question about line break reall easy to do with stringbuilder , maybe add a line break in there on the SB.Append()  ??  since he really wanted it instead of a comma

Comment: Good point, I added a suggestion to use AppendLine if he finds it suitable

Comment: I'm confused about the embedding of the <BR /> tags. I can't do that in the code behind, right? Ideally I want each item to be listed on a new line. I really like this approach..

Comment: Nevermind, looks like you can use it there now:                      if (chkBend.Checked) SB.Append("Bend/Stoop <br />");
This worked. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can set the Text that you want to append to your string in on of the CheckBox's properties, like ToolTip, if you don't use it.
Then you can use  this loop :

```
string s = "";
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if (item is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox temp = item as CheckBox;
                if (temp.Checked)
                {
                    s += temp.ToolTip + ", ";
                }
            }
        }
s = s.Substring(0,s.length-3);
```

The 's' has the string that you want;

Comment: The problem in general with building a list using concatenation is that we have to deal with the last trailing separator.

Comment: @Laurent No,you can Substring() the result at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try the CheckBoxList control in asp.net. Example here : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result using less line code. I enjoy working with List this way because I dont have to handle the trailing separator.

```
var checkBoxes = new CheckBox[] {chkBend, chkDryDusty, chkHearing, ...}
var values = new string[] {"Bend/Stoop", "Dry/Dusty", "Hearing", ...}

var selectedEntries = new List<string>();

for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    if (checkBoxes[i].Checked)
        selectedEntries.Add(values[i]);
}

if (TextBox1.Text != "")
    selectedEntries.Add(TextBox1.Text);

LblLimits.Text = string.Join(", ", selectedEntries.ToArray());
```

As proposed in comments, I think the multiple checkbox is the best solution.

If you need a line break:

```
LblLimits.Text = string.Join("<br/>", selectedEntries.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this as well. The more I know, the better.